# How to get data from settings json to mvc 6 view?

Tags: razor, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to load all settings key value pair from json file at once and use the settings key value in mvc 6 view page where required.I would be grateful if best solution is provided.I have a scenerio  as below

```
if(Settings.enable_logo_text)
{
<span>Settings.logo_text</span>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects) regarding the new configuration and options is quite good, I would recommend having a look there first.

Following the guidance provided there, start by creating a POCO class for your settings:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string logo_text { get; set; }
    public bool enable_logo_text { get; set; }
}
```

Update the `ConfigureServices` method of your startup class so you read your settings from the configured Configuration and is then available as a service that can be injected wherever you need to:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration);
    services.AddOptions();
}
```

If you want to use a the appsettings.json file, make sure you also build your `Configuration` object including that json file. For example:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

This way you can configure your values in the appsettings.json file and the values will be set on your `Settings` class:

```
{
  ...

  "enable_logo_text": true,
  "logo_text": "My Logo Text"
}
```

Finally, you can access the configured values by adding a `IOptions<Settings>` dependency. The most straightforward way would be to directly inject the options into the view (as explained in [the docs](https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/dependency-injection.html?highlight=view%20injection)), but you might want to consider injecting the options into the controller and passing them to the view in a more controlled way:

```
@inject IOptions<Settings> Settings
...
@if(Settings.Value.enable_logo_text)
{
    <span>@Settings.Value.logo_text</span>

}
```